# NHibernate Designer - many to many

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, many-to-many, designer

Following on from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148370/fluent-nhibernate-visual-designer), I am evaluating MindScape's NHibernate Designer.

When I add a many to many mapping, it says that it won't propagate this to the database..

Is there a way to map the many to many using this tool (a code generator). If I manually edit the mappings xml I lose it on changing the model.

The produced map:

```
<bag name='Roles' table='`RoleUser`'>
  <key column='`UserId`' />
  <many-to-many column='`RoleId`' class='Role' />
</bag>
```

I don't want to create an entity item_item and do a one to many on that link table as this should be done by the designer (adding an entity pollutes the business objects and is wrong).

Their [help documents](http://www.mindscapehq.com/help/nhdesigner/Index.aspx) say that this can happen if you set the source column name, and destination column name... Not working!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am one of the developers of the NHibernate designer.

Earlier versions of the designer didn't support generating the database schema for many-to-many associations.  This limitation has been removed in the latest version.  You can get the latest version through the VS2010 Extension Manager Updates tab.

Comment: Thanks mate - I was actually the one who requested it on your forums. The response was very quick... Impressed with Mindscape!!